# Cancelling/Exiting Photo Library in Android using react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image-picker, react-native-image-crop-picker

In my React Native app, I use the `react-native-image-crop-picker` package to have access to user's photo library.

It works nicely but if the user has no images in his/her photo library, I want to give the user a way to cancel out or exit it. How do I do that? Currently in Android, I click the element e.g. button or menu item to access user's photo library but then I get stuck there -- see image below:

[image]

And if I use gestures to get back to my app, I get the following warning.

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

My code is pretty basic at this point. When the user presses a button, I call this function which invokes the image picker:

pickImage() {

```
  ImagePicker.openPicker({
     width: 400,
     height: 250,
     cropping: true
  }).then(image => {
     onFilePicked(image);
  });
```

}

Basically, I just need to give the user a way to cancel out of picking an image from the photo gallery. I'd appreciate some pointers on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The npm package `react-native-image-crop-picker` is the most used library in react-native to choose Images and videos across the platforms.

It opens a default native Intent from which we can select media files from the gallery, **We are not able to customize the view of it** as its pure native intent is available into the native device.

And the error message `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection` We get is the default error from the library, when the user goes back into our app without selecting a single image or video.

To handle the error message we have to wrap our code inside to try and catch it.

For Ex:

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
     width: 400,
     height: 250,
     cropping: true
  }).then(image => {
     onFilePicked(image);
  }).catch(err => {
     console.log('Error : ', err.message)
  });

// - OR -

try {
    const imagePickerRes = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
        width: 400,
        height: 250,
        cropping: true
    })
    console.log('imagePicker Result : ', imagePickerRes)
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error : ', err.message)
}
```